# Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit WiFi connected, but no internet access

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet

UPC router has two WiFi networks: Private and Public called UPC Wi-Free. Second one stop working. Notebook connect to WiFi network (connection established) but cannot access any address on internet (for instace DNS server). UPC WiFi private network works fine. I try connect to this UPC Wi-Free network on another UPC router with same result. I try connect to this UPC Wi-Free network with second notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and it still working. I did not find any software update on my notebook in this period, when WiFi stop working. I ask UPC provider and they say, that they change nothing in they network in this period. So nothing changed, but this network stop working. Here is a output from nmcli: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqswhXYtBX/.
How I can find what is wrong with connection to this network?

Comment: What's the output of `ping 1.1.1.1`?

Comment: Output of ping 1.1.1.1 is: Destination host unreachable. By the way, I do not see previous answer and my comment to this answer.  Is it posible to delete this?

Comment: I try tcpdump command to find why it is not working. But I do not understood this output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CKPptcrPW2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not known what was exactly wrong, but when I clone MAC address, it start working. I suppose that in this WiFi network was/is something wrong with ARP tables.